# ElasticSearch cannot open . Only showing authentication panel for entering username and password

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem in my elasticsearch.

I downloaded from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch. I couldn't open the page.

I only see a pop-up menu for an authentication (username and password) when I use https://localhost:9200/ . Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Here is the screenshot shown below.
[image]

When I go to localhost:9200 in Postman , I get this error messsage shown below.

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "unable to authenticate with provided credentials and anonymous access is not allowed for this request",
                "additional_unsuccessful_credentials": "oauth2 token: invalid token",
                "header": {
                    "WWW-Authenticate": [
                        "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"",
                        "ApiKey"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "unable to authenticate with provided credentials and anonymous access is not allowed for this request",
        "additional_unsuccessful_credentials": "oauth2 token: invalid token",
        "header": {
            "WWW-Authenticate": [
                "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"",
                "ApiKey"
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": 401
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch latest version(8.0) comes with basic security, hence you see the pop-up for authentication, you need to provide the username(`elastic` which is reserved name) and it's password (printed on Elasticsearch logs when you start the service).